# How to tell if a WebView request succeeded?

Tags: android

I have a WebView that initially isn't visible to the user. When the page has finished loading I'm going to show it.

The problem is that `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()` gets called both when the request succeeds and when it fails. It seems awkward to add an `isPageLoadFailed` field and set that to `true` within `onReceivedError()` and then check that field within `onPageFinished()`.

Is there a simpler way to tell whether the page load actually succeeded?

Comment: Just to clarify, is it *errors* you would like to catch or a specific HTTP status code? Cause a 500, from the perspective of a Web view/Web browser is a successfully rendered page.

Answer (score 0):

Override WebViewClient and implement [onReceivedError](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError%28android.webkit.WebView,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). The top of that documentation page highlights all the errors you will get notified for. It may not include all the cases you expect but looking over the documentation, it looks like the best bet.

Comment: `onReceiveError()` is not called for HTTP errors (5xx, 4xx, etc). it is only called for network-related issues. shocking, but true.